# Test controller cover only 10%

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, custom-controller

i'm trying to do a test class for my controller...
but cover only 10%

controller:

```
public with sharing class CheckInController {
    // Geo location: longitude and latitude
    public String geolocation {get; set;}
    // Post text
    public String text {get; set;}
    // Error or Info
    public String error {get;set;}
    public Visita__c visit {get;set;}
    public Account conta {get;set;}
    public String IDparam {get;set;}
    public Decimal la;
    public Decimal lo;
    public String visitID;
    public Datetime[] checkout = new Datetime[10];


    public Datetime[] getcheckout() {
        return checkout;
    }
    public void setcheckout (Datetime[] checkout) {
        this.checkout = checkout;
    }

    public CheckInController(ApexPages.StandardController con) {
        conta = new Account();
        //visit = new Visita__c();
        visit =   (Visita__c)con.getRecord();
        IDparam = '';
        visitID = '';
    }

    public PageReference IdParam(){
        System.debug('IDparam: ' + IDparam);
        return null;
    }

    // Post to chatter with geolocation
    public void checkIn() {
        // Check if geolocation found or not
        if(geolocation==null || geolocation.length() == 8) {
            error = 'Não conseguimos captar a sua localização!';
            return;
        }

        if(text == null || text.trim().length()==0) {
            error = 'Nada para postar.';
            return;
        }

        try {
            Visita__c visita = new Visita__c();
            visita.Conta__c = visit.Conta__c;
            visita.Assunto__c = 'VIP - Visita VIP';
            visita.Atribuido_a__c =  Userinfo.getUserId();
            visita.Inicio__c = datetime.now();
            visita.Fim__c = datetime.now();
            visita.Check_in__c = datetime.now();
            visita.Descricao__c = text;

            String lati = geolocation.substring(0,geolocation.indexOf(','));
            String longi = geolocation.substring(geolocation.indexOf(',')+1);

            visita.Latitude_Checkin__c = decimal.valueof(lati);
            visita.Longitude_Checkin__c = decimal.valueof(longi);
            visita.Quantidade_Kits_Entregues__c = visit.Quantidade_Kits_Entregues__c;
            visita.Visita_Realizada_com_Sucesso__c = visit.Visita_Realizada_com_Sucesso__c;
            insert visita;
            error = 'Visita criada com sucesso!';

            // Post to chatter of current user
            FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
            post.ParentId =  visita.Id;
            post.Body = 'Check In realizado no cliente.' + visita.Conta__r.Name;
            post.Type = 'LinkPost';
            post.LinkUrl = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?q=' + geolocation;
            insert post;
            //error = 'Check In efetuado com sucesso!';
            visitID = visita.Id;
            error = 'Visita e Feed criados com sucesso!';
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            //error = ex.getMessage();
            error = 'Erro inesperado ao criar visita.';
        }
    }


    public void checkOut() {
         // Check if geolocation found or not
         if(geolocation==null || geolocation.length() == 8) {
             error = 'Não conseguimos captar a sua localização!';
             return;
         }

         if(text == null || text.trim().length()==0) {
             error = 'Nada para postar.';
             return;
         }

         try {
             Visita__c upvisita = new Visita__c();
             if (IDparam != '') {
                 upvisita.Id = IDparam;
             } else {
                 upvisita.Id = visitID;
             }

             //upvisita.Conta__c = visit.Conta__c;
             //upvisita.Assunto__c = 'VIP - Visita VIP';
             //upvisita.Atribuido_a__c =  Userinfo.getUserId();
             //upvisita.Inicio__c = datetime.now();
             //upvisita.Fim__c = datetime.now();
             //upvisita.Check_in__c = datetime.now();
             upvisita.Check_out__c = datetime.now();
             upvisita.Descricao__c = text;

             String lati = geolocation.substring(0,geolocation.indexOf(','));
             String longi = geolocation.substring(geolocation.indexOf(',')+1);

             upvisita.Latitude_CheckOut__c = decimal.valueof(lati);
             upvisita.Longitude_Checkout__c = decimal.valueof(longi);
             upvisita.Quantidade_Kits_Entregues__c = visit.Quantidade_Kits_Entregues__c;
             upvisita.Visita_Realizada_com_Sucesso__c = visit.Visita_Realizada_com_Sucesso__c;
             update upvisita;
             error = 'Visita atualizada com sucesso!';

             // Post to chatter of current user
             FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
             post.ParentId =  upvisita.Id;
             post.Body = 'Check Out realizado no cliente' + upvisita.Conta__r.Name;
             post.Type = 'LinkPost';
             post.LinkUrl = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?q=' + geolocation;
             insert post;
             //error = 'Check In efetuado com sucesso!';

             error = 'Visita e Feed atualizados com sucesso!';
         } catch(Exception ex) {
             //error = ex.getMessage();
            error = 'Erro inesperado ao atualizar visita.';
         }
    }
}
```

test class

```
@isTest
private class CheckInControllerTest {
    static String geolocation {get; set;}
    static String error {get;set;}
    static String text {get;set;}

    @isTest(SeeAllData=true)
    static void testaCheckIn() {
        Account conta1 = new Account();
        Visita__c visita1 = new Visita__c();
        conta1.Name = 'Teste1';
        insert conta1;

        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(visita1);
        CheckInController controller = new CheckInController(sc);

        //visita 1 checkin
        if(Test.isRunningTest()) {
            if(geolocation==null || geolocation.length() == 8) {
                error = 'Não conseguimos captar a sua localização!';
                return;
            }
            if(text == null || text.trim().length()==0) {
                error = 'Nada para postar.';
                return;
            }
            try {
                visita1.Conta__c = conta1.Id;
                visita1.Assunto__c = 'VIP - Visita VIP';
                visita1.Atribuido_a__c =  Userinfo.getUserId();
                visita1.Inicio__c = datetime.now();
                visita1.Fim__c = datetime.now();
                visita1.Check_in__c = datetime.now();
                visita1.Descricao__c = 'teste visita 1';
                visita1.Latitude_Checkin__c = 22.0642454;
                visita1.Longitude_Checkin__c = 48.3737058;
                visita1.Quantidade_Kits_Entregues__c = 22;
                visita1.Visita_Realizada_com_Sucesso__c = 'sim';
                insert visita1;

                FeedItem post1 = new FeedItem();
                post1.ParentId =  visita1.Id;
                post1.Body = 'Check In realizado no cliente.' + visita1.Conta__r.Name;
                post1.Type = 'LinkPost';
                post1.LinkUrl = 'https://www.google.com.br/maps/@-22.0786423,-48.3525056,15z';
                insert post1;
                //visitID = visita1.Id; 
            } catch(Exception e) {
                system.assertEquals(e.getMessage(), e.getMessage());
            }
        }




        //visita 1 checkout
        If(Test.isRunningTest()) {
            if(geolocation==null || geolocation.length() == 8) {
                error = 'Não conseguimos captar a sua localização!';
                return;
            }

            if(text == null || text.trim().length()==0) {
                error = 'Nada para postar.';
                return;
            }
            try {
                Visita__c upvisita1 = new Visita__c();
                upvisita1.Id = visita1.Id;
                upvisita1.Check_out__c = datetime.now();
                upvisita1.Descricao__c = 'bla bla bla bla1';    
                upvisita1.Latitude_CheckOut__c = 22.0642454;
                upvisita1.Longitude_Checkout__c = 48.3737058;
                upvisita1.Quantidade_Kits_Entregues__c = 11;
                upvisita1.Visita_Realizada_com_Sucesso__c = 'sim';
                update upvisita1;

                FeedItem uppost1 = new FeedItem();
                uppost1.ParentId =  upvisita1.Id;
                uppost1.Body = 'Check Out realizado no cliente' + upvisita1.Conta__r.Name;
                uppost1.Type = 'LinkPost';
                uppost1.LinkUrl = 'https://www.google.com.br/maps/@-22.0786423,-48.3525056,15z';
                insert uppost1;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                system.assertEquals(e.getMessage(), e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

can someone help me?

Comment: First thing would be to not use `seeAllData` and have `System.assert`'s so you can actually test where exactly your class is failing.

Comment: Is it just me or it looks like you just copy-pasted the methods into the test methods?. In the test, what you should do is to call the methods you are testing, and check that the values provided are the expected ones. For example, you should not insert a `Visita` but check that a `visita` was inserted and with the values you expect. And have something like `controller.checkIn();` before checking what is suppose to happen on check-in, etc.  
By the way, I find it odd that you call it controller when it is an extension, but well...

Comment: have change my code to:
controller.checkIn();
        controller.checkOut();
now, cover 22%...what i am still doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the most common question types that we get here. As such, there are a lot of similar questions here that you can search for that would provide guidance. Some people like to close questions like these as duplicates, but I personally like to go for repetition (the more times it's solved, the easier it is to find).

There are a few issues I see with your test class right off the bat:

- Using `seeAllData=true` (this one is more of a red flag. It's not best practice)
- Only one `testMethod`
- No assertions

The fundamental rule of unit testing is **you only obtain coverage for code that is executed as part of a test method**. However, code coverage is only a secondary goal. The *primary goal* of unit testing is **to ensure that your code behaves correctly**.

It'll probably help you if you adjust your perspective about unit tests. Right now, it looks like you have one test that tries to cover everything. Generally, speaking, one test will not be able to sufficiently cover a class. Instead, try looking at testing in terms of "What happens if I call this one method, with this specific input?"

That approach will naturally lead to having multiple test methods. By having multiple tests, with different inputs each time, that only test small portions of your code, you will naturally gain the coverage you need. On top of that, if you test enough inputs, you can be confident that your code is *robust* (that is, able to gracefully handle adverse situations).

Some examples to get you going down the right path

```java
@isTest
private class MyTestClass{
    // Current best practice is to use a method annotated with @testSetup to set up the
    //   common data used by all tests (or rather, the data that isn't specific to 
    //   any one test).
    // At any rate, it's better practice to create all of your test data in your test class
    //   (as opposed to using seeAllData=true) because it gives you control over the
    //   inputs that you supply to the methods you're testing.
    // Predictable input leads to predictable output.
    // Creating all of your test data inside the test class also means you don't run 
    //   the risk of altering real data.
    @testSetup
    static void setupEnvironment(){
        // With that said, it doesn't look like you have any data that needs to be set up
    }

    // Specifying @testMethod, and using static testMethod void myTest(){} do the same
    //   thing.
    // I prefer using the annotation, because it makes disabling the test a lot easier.
    // To disable this test, you simply need to comment out one line (the @testMethod 
    //   annotation) instead of commenting out the entire test.
    @testMethod
    static void testConstructor(){
        // The goal of each test is to target one specific portion of code.
        // The less you test at once, the easier it is to test.
        // Like the method name suggests, we want to test the constructor in this test.

        // Phase 1 of unit testing: setting up the test environment
        // There's not much to do here, given your current controller extension
        Visita__c visita1 = new Visita__c();

        // Also part of phase 1 would be things like creating the standardController
        //   instance that you'll pass into your constructor
        ApexPages.standardController stdCon = new ApexPages.StandardController(visita1);

        // Phase 2 of unit testing: executing the test
        // This is generally pretty short, just executing the one method you're targeting.

        // I like to wrap this section (and only this section) in Test.startTest()/Test.stopTest().
        // Doing so gives you a new set of governor limits.
        // If you limit that to just the line of code that you're executing, that gives
        //   you the ability to make assertions against how much of the governor limits
        //   your method consumed.
        // It might not be important for you now, but it becomes more important when
        //   your code interacts with more things or the amount of data in your org becomes large
        Test.startTest();
        CheckInController controller = new CheckInController(stdCon);
        Test.stopTest();

        // Phase 3 of unit testing: verifying results
        // It's important to verify that your code does what you think it does.
        // To do that, we use assertions.
        // If your code changes a variable, performs DML on a record, etc..., that
        //   is something that you want to assert actually happened.

        // For this test, the controller should set conta, visit, IDParam, and visitID
        // assertEquals() and assertNotEquals() only require 2 parameters, but can
        //   accept a third parameter.
        // The third parameter is a message that gets printed when the assertion fails, and
        //   helps identify what the issue is.
        // I know no Portuguese, so error messages in English.
        System.assertNotEquals(null, controller.conta, 'We expected the constructor to initialize conta, but it did not');

        System.assertNotEquals(null, controller.visit, 'We expected the constructor to initialize visit, but it did not');

        // Beyond asserting that controller.visit is not null, we want to make sure that
        //   it is the exact same thing that we passed into the constructor.
        System.assertEquals(visita1, controller.visit, 'visit should be equal to the instance that we set up as part of the test');

        // More simple checks that variables were initialized
        System.assertNotEquals(null, controller.IDparam, 'IDparam was null when it should have been initialized');
        System.assertNotEquals(null, controller.visitID, 'visitID was null when it should have been intiailized');
    }

    @testMethod
    static void testGetCheckout(){
        // We'll go through the same 3 phases of unit testing here too

        Visita__c visita1 = new Visita__c();

        // Also part of phase 1 would be things like creating the standardController
        //   instance that you'll pass into your constructor
        ApexPages.standardController stdCon = new ApexPages.StandardController(visita1);

        // We need to have an instance of your controller extension class to proceed.
        // Even though we're not testing this portion of code, it's ok to have it here.
        // Setting up the controller extension instance just becomes part of your test setup
        //   (phase 1)
        CheckInController controller = new CheckInController(stdCon);

        // Phase 2 of unit testing: executing the test
        Test.startTest();
        // This time, the method we're testing returns a result.
        // We want to capture the return value so we can assert against it in phase 3.
        List<DateTime> results = controller.getcheckout();
        Test.stopTest();

        // Phase 3: verifying results
        System.assertNotEquals(null, results, 'We should have gotten a non-null list as a result of calling getcheckout()');

        // In addition to not being null, your code initializes checkout to a
        //   specific state.
        // We need to assert that the state of that variable is what we think it should be.
        System.assertNotEquals(true, results.isEmpty(), 'The controller extension initializes checkout to not be empty, but we got an empty list as a result');

        // Getting even more specific, it was initialized to have 10 elements.
        // That's worthy of asserting.
        // We could have just done this last assertion instead of this one + the two
        //   before it, but breaking things down to this level of granularity
        //   makes it easier to figure out what precisely is going wrong when this
        //   testMethod fails.
        // On the other hand, the value '10' here is a 'magic number'.
        // 'Magic numbers' are generally bad because it's often hard to tell why
        //   that specific value was chosen.
        // If the thing that determines what value a 'magic number' has changes, then
        //   this assertion will fail, and it won't be apparent why.
        // It's much better to derive the first value in an assertion (the value
        //   we're asserting against), but that's tough to do in this particular situation.
        System.assertEquals(10, results.size(), 'checkout should have 10 entries in it by default');
    }
}
```

I could go into more detail, but I hope that my examples tell you the direction that you need to go in, and provide enough detail for you to finish writing the rest of the tests yourself.

One thing that I didn't cover was that it is perfectly fine (and further, I'd argue good practice) to have multiple test methods for a single method in the class you're testing.

If the portion of code you're testing happens to have an `if(<condition>){ // code} else { // other code}`, then you can only test either the `if` portion, or the `else` portion in a single run of the code that is being tested.

You could have one test that makes 2 parallel runs of your code, but better practice is to break those up into individual test methods. Besides making the setup easier, it (again) makes it easier to see where things are going wrong if you break tests up into multiple methods.

Along the same line of thought, you also want to be testing more that just the 'happy path', where all of your input is well-formed. Users are very adept at finding ways to break things, so a good test class will take this into account.

For example, if you have a method that accepts an `Id` as a parameter, you shouldn't assume that it will never be null, or even for the correct object. You still want to test the 'happy path' to make sure that the behavior is correct when the input is correct, but you'll also want to test what happens when the Id is null (a separate test), as well as another separate test to see what happens if you, say, pass an Id for an `Opportunity` when your happy path expects an If for an `Account`.

Yes, that can lead to a lot of tests, and it takes time to write and maintain those tests. Determining what is/isn't worth the time to test takes practice. One upside to having lots of tests though is that it makes it harder for you (or others) to break your code in the future.

Comment: hey, how i test the part of "checkIn()" and "checkout()" where have :
"
            FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
            post.ParentId =  visita.Id;
            post.Body = 'Check In realizado no cliente.' + visita.Conta__r.Name;
            post.Type = 'LinkPost';
            post.LinkUrl = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?q=' + geolocation;
            insert post;
"

Comment: @BrunoGomes The same way you test the other parts. - Set up the data you need for the test to run. - Execute one specific piece of code. - Use assertions to verify that the changes you think your code made were indeed made. This is quickly heading into territory where asking a new question would be appropriate, but I'll give you one more hint. The code you're asking about in your comment is below a DML `insert` inside of a `try` block. If you're not covering the code right after the insert, you must be not executing that code. What do you think could cause that? Seems like a test setup issue.

Comment: i got 82% cover test...thanks for help, man!